# Swagger throws 400 error when optional query is not included

Tags: java, spring, url, swagger

I have defined an endpoint in Spring, and defined a single ApiParam as optional.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchResult/getList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "populate list")
public JasonMessage getList(@ApiParam(name="id", value = "id", required = false)
                            @RequestParam Integer id) {
```

However when I write the url without the `?id=xxx` parameter, I get a 400 error, which I expect is a malformed Url error.

Why is this? I have defined it as `required = false`, and it's not a path variable, however there's no way I can write the url without including at least an empty query parameter, like `?id=`.

Am I confused about what is a genuinely optional parameter for URLs, is it an issue with swagger, an issue with spring, or a mistake I have made somewhere.

The response body is `no content` and the Response Code is just `400`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your annotation to `@RequestParam(required = false)` the required field is defaulted to `true`. Additionally you can delete the `required` on `@ApiParam` because swagger will detect that from Springs annotations.

Remember, Swagger annotations are for additional information about your api and have NO impact on functionality of endpoints (outside their api page which is generated).

Additionally you should put the name of your request parameter on the `@RequestParam` annotation, this is again because Swagger annotations have no effect on Springs behavior.

Your final code should read

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchResult/getList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "populate list")
public JasonMessage getList(@ApiParam
                            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {
```

Comment: You beautiful person. That is exactly it! That makes so much sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JDGale8 Your welcome! When working with Swagger+Spring I would recommend just doing Spring annotations then adding additional Swagger annotations on to decorate or correct the endpoints. Swagger is very good at grabbing behavior from Springs annotations. For instance you could remove the `@ApiParam` annotation all together from that endpoint cause Swagger knows that already. (Unless you have it configured otherwise)